# Getting the query portion of the URL and performing an action on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Im currently creating a website for one of my classes in school.

I want the site to be setup so it doesn't look like its reloading.

BY doing the pages in a query: `?page=index`.
I do this by fading in the Div depending on the query. I know the page actually reloads, but it doesnt look like its not reloading with the fade. You can see my site here: http://yolatools.yolasite.com/resources/project.html?page=index

Now the only problem is that when I do `?page=fcduj` its suppose to show the page not found DIV.

My code is:

```
function load(){
  var profile=location.search;
  if(profile=="?page=index") 
  {
    $('.section, #home').fadeIn(1500);
    $('.i').addClass('active');
    $('.a, .m').addClass('grey');
  }
  else if(profile=="?page=about")
  {
    $('.section, #about').fadeIn(1500);
    $('.a').addClass('active');
    $('.m, .i').addClass('grey');
  }
  else if(profile=="?page=more"){
    $('.section, #more').fadeIn(1500);
    $('.m').addClass('active');
    $('.a, .i').addClass('grey');
  }
  else if(profile==="")
  {
    location.href = '?page=index';
  }
  if(profile !== '?page=index' && profile !== '?page=about'  && profile !== '?page=more') {
    var rsts = profile.substr(6);
    $('#query').html(rsts);
    $('#wrong').fadeIn(1500);
  }
}
```

I launch this function with `onload` in the `body` tag.

The part that is suppose to make the Page not found DIV to show is:

```
if(profile !== '?page=index' && profile !== '?page=about'  && profile !== '?page=more') {
  var rsts = profile.substr(6);
  $('#query').html(rsts);
  $('#wrong').fadeIn(1500);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to be working, but I have no Idea why. For the `?page=index` I don't want to use `PHP` even though that's usually used with PHP. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `#wrong` div is shown, but the parent `.section` div is not shown.

Change that if statement to:

```
if(profile !== '?page=index' && profile !== '?page=about'  && profile !== '?page=more') {
  var rsts = profile.substr(6);
  $('#query').html(rsts);
  $('.section, #wrong').fadeIn(1500);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I forgot that I have `.section` hidden by default. Thanks for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom 404 error page, that has the needed JS

Answer (score 0):

replace your javascript with this:

```
function home(){

$('#home').fadeIn(1000);

$('#about, #more').fadeOut(10);

}

function about(){

$('#about').fadeIn(1000);

$('#home, #more').fadeOut(100);

}

function more(){

$('#more').fadeIn(1000);

$('#about, #home').fadeOut(100);

}

function menu(){$('#h1').fadeIn(1000);setTimeout('other()',1000)}

function other(){

$('#h3').fadeIn(500);

setTimeout('$("#menu").fadeIn(500);', 500)

}

function load(){

var profile=location.search;
if(profile=="?page=index")

{

$('.section, #home').fadeIn(1500);setTimeout('menu()', 1500)

}

else if(profile=="?page=about")

{

$('.section, #about').fadeIn(1500);setTimeout('menu()', 1500)

}

else if(profile=="?page=more"){

$('.section, #more').fadeIn(1500);setTimeout('menu()', 1500)

}

else if(profile==="")

{

location.href = '?page=index';

}



else {

var rsts = profile.substr(6);

$('#query').html(rsts);

$('#wrong,#articles').fadeIn(1500);

$('#about, #more, #home').hide();

}



}
```